# OnClick events not working in ASP.NET page

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, postback, dopostback

I am having a aspx page which inherits from a master page.
In the master page I have a button that is common for every page in the solution.

```
<div class="btn_general_mid">
<asp:Button 
    ID="btnMainSearch" 
    ValidationGroup="MainSearch" 
    OnClientClick="CheckSearchTextBox()"
    CausesValidation="true" 
    runat="server" 
    OnClick="btnMainSearch_Click"  
    CssClass="search_btn_submit"
    Text="Search" />
</div>
```

Here the `CheckSearchTextBox()` is a javascript function and the `btnMainSearch_Click` is the event which is handling the code behind part of the button.

In a certain page this button click event `btnMainSearch_Click` is not fired. (The debugger does not reach that in the code)

In the runtime, (When examined using Firebug) this is the code segment generated for the button.

```
<div class="btn_general_mid">
<input id="ctl00_btnMainSearch" 
class="search_btn_submit" 
type="submit"    
onclick="CheckSearchTextBox();WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new  WebForm_PostBackOptions("ctl00$btnMainSearch", "", true, "MainSearch", "", false, false))" 
value="Search" 
name="ctl00$btnMainSearch"></div>
```

Actually in the other pages where this button works fine , the same html output is generated for this button. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Is your Javascript CheckSearchTextBox() function causing an error, by any chance? This would prevent the subsequent ASP.NET postback.

Comment: No. Actually that part is working fine.. :-(

Comment: Is the postback HTTP request made? If it is, what is the response? Check in the browser dev console.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check whether there are any validation errors because it would not allow server side event `btnMainSearch_Click` getting fired.

Comment: I can't thank you enough for this.. I was stuck on it for the whole day

Answer (score 10):

One reason for this is may be that postback is being stopped by some visible or apparently invisible validator. Try adding cause validation to false in button tag.

```
CausesValidation="false"
```

Comment: what if I want this with validation on my submit button click ?

Comment: My problem was, that I had a modal form and the button missed ValidationGroup (there was problem with validating a form in the background). Adding CausesValidation="false" can help to debug similar problems.