# Why my server side code is not firing on ASP.net Button click?

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery-ui, webforms, jquery-ui-dialog

I don't understand why my server side is not executed.

Here is my code

**ASP code**

```
<div class="row" style="padding-top:20px;">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <input id="btnSave" type="button" class="btn btn-info"  value="Save" />
        <input id="btnLoad" type="button" class="btn btn-info"  value="Load" />

         <%-- SAVE DIALOG  --%>
         <div id="saveDialog" title="Basic dialog">
         <div class="row">
             <div class="col-lg-4">
                 <asp:Label ID="lblFileName" CssClass="control-label" runat="server" Text="File Name"></asp:Label>
             </div>
             <div class="col-lg-6">
                 <asp:TextBox ID="txtFileName" CssClass="form-control" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
             </div>
         </div>
         <div class="row">
             <div class="col-lg-12" style="text-align:center;">
                 <asp:Label ID="lblSaveErrorMsg" runat="server" Text="" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label>
             </div>
         </div>
         <div class="row" style="padding-top:10px;">
             <div class="col-lg-12" style="text-align:center;">
                <asp:Button ID="btnSaveFile" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="btnSaveFile_Click"/>
                                
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>                   
</div>
```

**Server Side Code**

```
protected void btnSaveFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["xxx"].ConnectionString;

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
        {
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(ASPxPivotGrid1.SaveLayoutToString());
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);

            DateTime currentDate = DateTime.Now;

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO ReportSave(UserID,ReportName,UserFileName,ReportData,Time,ReportFilter)VALUES(@UserID,@ReportName,@UserFileName,@ReportData,@Time,@ReportFilter);";
            
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", UserID);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ReportName", ReportName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserFileName", txtFileName.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ReportData", stream);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Time", currentDate);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ReportFilter", txtFilterRecord.Text);

            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            //string message = "Your details have been saved successfully.";
            //string script = "window.onload = function(){ alert('";
            //script += message;
            //script += "')};";
            //ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "SuccessMessage", script, true);
        }
    }
```

**Note:**

> It doesn't show any error message and it is not reloading the page as well. It was weird.
>
> I call jquery functions, after it execute also it never call the server code. For testing purpose, I removed the entire jquery code for this button. So no Jquery function for this button now. But still I couldn't call the server side code why???

**UPDATED**

> I found something, I have one button on the form called `btnSave`, once user click it will call

```
$('#btnSave').click(function () {
    $('#saveDialog').dialog();
});
```

> **IMPORTANT NOTE:** Then Dialog box will appear. In that dialog box I have added that button `btnSaveFile`. But When I add this button outside the dialog, it's calling the server side code.

Comment: Your code looks fine so far. About the "ASP" code. This should be inside an ASPX file, which the server processed, not just a client side HTML file. I hope you have that right?

Comment: Do you have any jQuery attached to the form submit event?

Comment: @Pete no I removed it completely

Comment: @Marcel I don't understand what you are trying to say

Comment: If you view the html source, has the button been converted so the runat server no longer appears?

Comment: @pete can you check my update now

Answer (score 0):

Hey friend **protected void btnSaveFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)** copied this method from other page or application then it will not work, So delete the event and event name assigned to the button. Go to design and go to button even properties go to OnClick event double click it, It will generate event and automatically assigns event name to the button. It will work.

Or

Give the new Onclick function name in the code

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSaveFile" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="btnSaveFile_Click"/>
```

**Use full Links:**

[asp.net Button OnClick event not firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15569857/asp-net-button-onclick-event-not-firing)

[ASP.NET button not firing on click event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20798135/asp-net-button-not-firing-on-click-event)

[OnClick events not working in ASP.NET page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27038297/onclick-events-not-working-in-asp-net-page)

https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/681648/button-click-event-not-firing-asp-net

You may use this code in Jquery:

```
$(document).on('click', '#btnSave', function() {
{
   $('#saveDialog').dialog();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue recently.

Updating the button code as bellow helped me out with my issue:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSaveFile" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="btnSaveFile_Click" UseSubmitBehavior="false"/>
```

Using the UseSubmitBehavior as false allowed the page to refresh but still be able to trigger the function call. Where before, when the page refreshes it would stop the function from being able to be called